# Download source tracking ionic

Tags: android, ios, facebook, ionic-framework, ads

I am developing an Ionic application and the client wanted to implement source tracking.

In essence they would like to know that a user clicked on a facebook/instagram/twitter ad which led them to click the download button. Also if for example the user clicks on an ad downloads the app and then makes a purchase inside the app they would know that they first installed the app by clicking on a particular ad so they can organize their ad campaign accordingly.

Is this even possible with ionic?

I have been doing some research which suggest it's not but there seems to be something [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns?hl=en_US#general-campaigns) that indicates it is possible to be done native.

Am I trying to do something that's not possible in Ionic or is this possible to implement.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can be of help. [google-analytics-plugin](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin).

> To track a Screen (PageView)   w/ campaign details:
>     `window.ga.trackView('Screen Title', 'my-scheme://content/1111?utm_source=google&utm_campaign=my-campaign')`

Comment: I guess that this is something where I would manually enter a url from within the app. What I need is when you click from your phone on a facebook add where you get redirected to the store and download the app that from within the now downloaded app I know which campaign you clicked. 

I don't really think that's possible but just want to double check